# Merging/cleaning up Firestore Indexes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app currently has 154 indexes in Firestore.  They have been generated over time as new functionality has been added....and over time some sloppier processes have allowed for some Firebase projects to get indexes added (via the auto-create URLs in error messages) that other projects have yet to.

So I am looking to aggregate all of the index definitions across all of my Firebase projects -- it is a white-label app, same code and *mostly* the same configuration to each project....this is "clean up and synch up" time.

I am looking for a way to aggregate the dozen or so `firestore.index.json` files that I have in a way that:

1. doesn't lose any indexes
2. might recognize redundant indexes to filter them out

I wrote the following code to "flatten" and sort different Firestore index JSON files, so at least I can `diff` two projects' configurations.

```js
import fs from 'fs';

const filename = process.argv[2];
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8');
const jsonData = JSON.parse(fileContent);

/* the jsonData has the structure:
  {
    "indexes": [
      {
        "collectionGroup": "act",
        "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
        "fields": [
          {
            "fieldPath": "actNumber",
            "order": "ASCENDING"
          },
          {
            "fieldPath": "actStatus.name",
            "order": "ASCENDING"
          },
        ]
      }
    ]

Now convert each element of the array into a one-line string of format: "collectionGroup,fieldPath:order,fieldPath:order,...", sort, and output to console
*/

jsonData.indexes
  .map((index) => {
    const fieldStrings = index.fields.map((field) => `${field.fieldPath}:${field.order}`);
    return `${index.collectionGroup},${fieldStrings.join(',')}`;
  })
  .sort()
  .forEach((line) => console.log(line));
```

But I'm not sure how/where to turn for direction on "merging" indexes, or if that's even possible.

Comment: In general, on Stack Overflow, it's expected that you make an attempt at solving the problem, and if you get stuck, post the code that doesn't work the way you expect, or at least explain where you are stuck with the process.

Comment: I appreciate that, but before going into a deep investigation of what is likely a non-trivial algorithm, I thought I'd ask for suggestions/directions.  I did a number of searches and found a few answers here on SO that nibble on the edges...but nothing directional.

Comment: @DougStevenson - additional code/details added.  Thank you for your nudge on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't completely solved my OP but here is the solution I am going with for the time being.

The approach is:

1. get the JSON definition of the Firestore indexes for each project using `firebase firestore:indexes`
2. use function (I wrote it in JavaScript) to convert each JSON index definition into a single-line text that can easily be compared to others
3. cat all of the lines from all of the flattened JSON files together, keeping only unique lines
4. use another script to convert the unified set of unique lines back into the JSON structure of the `firestore.indexes.json` format

That unified JSON file is now able to be deployed to each of the projects using `firebase deploy --only firestore`

I wrote all of that and include the JavaScript code [in this blog post](https://www.buymeacoffee.com/gregfenton/firestore-indexes-got-out-of-sync).